# prove: $A+E$ is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose square matrix $A$ with order-n, and $A^TA=E,|A|=-1$, prove: $A+E$ is not invertible.

Here, $A^T$ is transpose, $|A|$ is determinant, $E$ is identity matrix.

#### Prove:

---

we will show $|A+E|=0$.

\begin{align}|A+E|=\left|A+A^T A\right|=\left|A\left(E+A^T\right)\right|=\left|A\left\|E+A^T\right.\right|=-\left|E+A^T\right|\end{align}

\begin{align}|A+E|=\left|(A+E)^T\right|=\left|A^T+E\right|=\left|E+A^T\right|\end{align}

so we've done.

Any problems? is that all?

Comment: You use $A+A^TA=A(E+A^T)$ which is true, but not as obvious as using $A+A^TA=(E+A^T)A$ (from then on it is similar). Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: In the first line you come from $|A+A^TA|=|A(E+A^T)|$, it should be $|A+A^T A|=|(E+A^T)A|$ but it doesn't change anything

Comment: This question is a special case of ["*Is sum of two orthogonal matrices singular?*"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491344/is-sum-of-two-orthogonal-matrices-singular/491435#491435) with $B=I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way is perhaps more complicated, but it is always good to solve the problem in more than one way:

Orthogonal (unitary) matrices always have eigenvalues lying in $S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| =1\}$. If $A$ is real, then its eigenvalues are either real, or come in complex conjugate pairs. $|A| = \prod_{i}\lambda_i$. So if any of the eigenvalues are complex, $\lambda_i \cdot \bar{\lambda_i} = 1$, so those factors don't contribute. Since all the factors are in $S^1$, the real factors are $\pm 1$. Since the product is $-1$, there must be at least one eigenvalue of $-1$ (in fact, the eigenvalue $-1$ must have odd multiplicity...algebraic and geometric multiplicity are the same, since $A$ is orthogonal). $A+I$ has eigenvalues of $A$ shifted by adding $1$ to each, so $A+I$ has an eigenvalue equal to $-1+1=0$, so it is singular.