# If $\vert A\vert+\vert B\vert =0,$ then What is the value of $\vert A+B\vert$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

> There are two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of same order such that
> $A^2=I$ and $B^2=I,$Where $I$ is a unit matrix.If $\vert A\vert+\vert
>  B\vert =0,$ then find the value of $\vert A+B\vert ,$here $\vert
>  A\vert$ denotes the determinant of matrix $A$

*Solution:* Since $A^2=I$
then Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that the characteristic polynomial of last equation is $\lambda_A^2-1=0\implies \lambda_A=+1,-1$.

Since the product of Eigenvalues of a matrix is equal to the determinant of the matrix,So$\vert A\vert =(+1)(-1)=-1\tag{1}$.

Similarly,Since $B^2=I$
then Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that the characteristic polynomial of last equation is $\lambda_B^2-1=0\implies \lambda_B=+1,-1$.

Since the product of Eigenvalues of a matrix is equal to the determinant of the matrix,So$\vert B\vert =(+1)(-1)=-1\tag{2}$.

Equations $(1)$ & $(2)$ implies that $\vert A\vert +\vert B\vert=-2$

But,it is given that $\vert A\vert+\vert B\vert =0$

Please point out my mistake??

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Where is the mistake in the approach?" says nothing about the subject of the question, it's a useless title.

Comment: $A$ could already be the identity...

Comment: @Jan:yeah that is one case only,I want to know what is wrong with method

Comment: But then $A$ does also satisfy $A ² = I$ but there is no negative eigenvalue

Comment: Lets assume that $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. You deduce from $A ² = I$ that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $-1$. But that does not need to be true

Comment: @Jan:is there any relation between Eigenvalues of $A+B$ and  Eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ do not commute, then we expect no formula for the eigenvalues of $A+B$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and of $B$.

Comment: For a very simple answer, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4420205). This question can be viewed as a variant of “$A,B\in O(n)$ and $\det(A)=-\det(B)\,\Rightarrow\det(A+B)=0$”, to which an answer [in the same vein](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/491435) has been given.

Answer (score 4):

This question is interesting and a little more complicated than it looks like. I also know that the question of the OP is about a mistake but I felt that a solution to this problem would be welcome. Perhaps some future readers will find that helpful.

So, here we go. As already pointed out, the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ for chosen matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfying $A^2=B^2=I$ is given by $p(x)=x^2-1$ or by one of its factors, i.e. $x+1$ or $x-1$. This means that the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ can only take the values -1 and 1. From the expressions $A^2-I=0$ and $B^2-I=0$, we also get that $A=A^{-1}$ and $B=B^{-1}$.

Now since the determinant of if the product of the eigenvalues, then the determinant of those matrices can either be 1 or -1. This means that if the sum of $|A|$ and $|B|$ needs to be zero, then we necessarily have that one matrix has an even number of eigenvalues equal to -1 while the other has an odd number. This is formalized as follows

$$|A|+|B|=|A|(1+|A^{-1}||B|)=|A|(1+|A||B|)=|A|(1+|AB|)$$

where we have used the usual determinant product rules and the fact that $A=A^{-1}$ since $A^2=I$. Since $|A|\ne0$ then we must have that $1+|AB|=1+|A||B|=0$ which means that we need to have $|A|=1$ and $|B|=-1$, or vice-versa.

Assume now that $|A|=1$ and $|B|=-1$. We need to find what is $|A+B|$. The issue here is that there is no general formula for the eigenvalues of a sum of two matrices except in few cases; e.g. simultaneously diagonalizable, etc.

For that we consider the characteristic polynomial $q(x):=|xI-AB|$. Using determinant formulas and the facts that $A=A^{-1}$ and $B=B^{-1}$, we get that

$$q(x)=|A|\cdot|xA-B|\ \mathrm{and}\ q(x)=|B|\cdot|xB-A|.$$

Since, $|A|=1$ and $|B|=-1$, we get that

$$|xA-B|=-|xB-A|.$$ Substituting $x=-1$ yields that

$$(-1)^n|A+B|=(-1)^{n+1}|B+A|$$ which implies that $|A+B|=0$. This also means that $AB$ has an eigenvalue at $-1$.

Comment: Nicely done. (I also believe this was the intended question)

Comment: From $A^2=I$ alone we cannot deduce the minimal polynomial is $x^2-1$, though we *can* deduce the minimal polynomial divides $x^2-1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, you are correct. I did not express my myself very well. What I mean that this was a minimal polynomial for the whole classes of matrices such that $A^2=I$ but it is true that if $A$ is chosen then the minimal polynomial can be one of the factors of $A^2-I$. I have improved my answer.

Answer (score 2):

"then Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that the characteristic polynomial of last equation is $\lambda_A^2-1=0\implies \lambda_A=+1,-1$."

This implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ are contained in the set $\{-1,+1\}$. So in general they're something like $-1, -1, -1, \ldots, +1,+1,+1,\ldots$. So the determinant is $(-1)^r(+1)^s$ where $r$ is the number of $-1$'s, $s$ is the number of $+1$'s and $r+s=n$, the size of the matrix.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @lcv The OP made the mistake of thinking that the eigenvalues are $+1$ and $-1$ (exactly those two, and without multiplicity). I made clear that the eigenvalues are **contained** in the set $\{+1, -1\}$ (so it could happen that only one of them is an eigenvalue), and also recalled that they must be considered with their multiplicities.