# Please help in leading further in: If $\vert A\vert+\vert B\vert =0,$ then find the value of $\vert A+B\vert$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, trace

> There are two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of same order such that
> $A^2=I$ and $B^2=I,$Where $I$ is a unit matrix.If $\vert A\vert+\vert
>  B\vert =0,$ then find the value of $\vert A+B\vert ,$here $\vert
>  A\vert$ denotes the determinant of matrix $A$

*Solution*:Let $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of order $n$.

Since $A^2=I$
then Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that the characteristic polynomial of last equation is

$\lambda_A^2-1=0\implies \lambda_A \in \{+1,-1\}\implies tr(A)\in\{-2,0,2\}\tag{1}$.

Since $B^2=I$
then Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that the characteristic polynomial of last equation is

$\lambda_B^2-1=0\implies \lambda_B \in \{+1,-1\}\implies tr(B)\in\{-2,0,2\}\tag{2}$.

Using equations $(1)$ and equation $(2)$ we  get $$tr(A+B)=tr(A)+tr(B)\in \{-4,-2,0,2,4\}$$

Now making use of **$\vert A\vert+\vert B\vert=0$**:If $\vert A\vert=1\implies \vert B\vert=-1$,this will lead to two cases

**Case1:**  Both Eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ $\implies$ Both Eigenvalues of $B$ are $-1$.So $tr(A)=n\implies tr(B)=-n$

**Case2:**  Both Eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1$ $\implies$ Both Eigenvalues of $B$ are $1$.So $tr(A)=-n\implies tr(B)=n$

Both Cases leads us to the conclusion $tr(A+B)=tr(A)+tr(B)=0$

Now $$(A+B)^2=(A+B)(A+B)=A^2+B^2+AB+BA$$
$$\implies (A+B)^2=I+I+AB+BA$$
$$\implies tr(A+B)^2=tr(I)+tr(I)+tr(AB)+tr(BA)$$
$$\implies tr(A+B)^2=n+n+2tr(AB)$$since $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$

Now we know that $$\vert P\vert=\frac{1}{2}[(tr(P))^2-tr(P^2)]$$

Putting $P=A+B$ in above equation we get

$$\vert A+B\vert=\frac{1}{2}[(tr(A+B))^2-tr((A+B)^2)]$$.

Since $tr(A+B)=0$,so we get $$\vert A+B\vert=\frac{1}{2}[-tr((A+B)^2)]$$.

$$\vert A+B\vert=\frac{1}{2}[-n-n-2tr(AB)]$$.

What to do next??

Is there anyother method other than the above method??

Comment: what's the source of this problem?  You state these are $n\times n$ matrices then repeatedly assume $n=2$ e.g. when talking about 'both' eigenvalues of $A$ or the possibilities for a trace of A or B and in writing $\vert P\vert=\frac{1}{2}[(tr(P))^2-tr(P^2)]$.  There also seems to be confusion between characteristic polynomials and annihilating polynomials.

Comment: @user8675309:I misuderstood the square matrices as order 2 matrices ,the relation i used is valid for order 2 matrices..The problem was asked in Indian Civil Services exam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From $A^2=B^2=I$ and $\det(A)+\det(B)=0$, we have $\det(A)=-\det(B)=\pm1$ and $(A+B)=A(B+A)B$. Taking determinants on both sides of the latter equality, we obtain $\det(A+B)=-\det(A+B)$. Therefore $\det(A+B)=0$ when the characteristic of the underlying field is not $2$.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what field you are working over; I assume you are considering matrices with real entries. The approach for complex entries is similar.

**Hint:**

- If $A^2 = I$, then $\Bbb R^n = \ker(A - I) \oplus \ker(A + I)$. That is, $\dim \ker(A - I) + \dim \ker(A + I) = n$, and $\ker(A - I) \cap \ker(A + I) = \{0\}$.
- $|A| = (-1)^{\dim \ker (A + I)}$
- We can deduce that either $\ker(A - I) \cap \ker(B + I)$ or $\ker(A + I) \cap \ker(B - I)$ contains a non-zero element. For a vector $x$ from either intersection,  we have $(A + B)x = 0$.

Comment: :What  technique you used for writing first bullet?

Comment: @P.Styles There are a few possible approaches here. The quickest is to note that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^2 - 1$ and therefore has no repeating factors, which means that $A$ is diagonalizable. Note that the subspaces $\ker(A \pm I)$ are eigenspaces.